# Splitting string twice ? in HTML Control Powerapps

Tags: html, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

Really looking to get some help on this project! It is so close! so any help would be massively appreciated.

So in the image example that first HTML table has hardcoded values and is what I want to end up with and the table below is dynamically getting the information but I am running into an issue as you can see.

[image]

I want to be able to split by the comma and then on a new line as well.

Here is the code below.

```
With(
    {
        Headers: Split("Power,Freq,Comp Intake,Exhaust,Eng Fresh Water,RW IN,RW OUT,Oil Sump,Inlet Manifold,Fuel Use,Boost,Engine Oil Press,Smoke,Blow by,Voltage,Current", ","),
        Units: Split("KWe,Hz,ºC,ºC,ºC,ºC,ºC,ºC,ºC,mm3/ST,Bar,Bar,FSN,L/min,volts,amps", ","),
        Measurements: [
            Concat(SortByColumns(Search(Filter('datasource',Len(data) > 20),TextInput3.Text,"serialno"),"loadord"),data) 
        ]
    },
    "<table border='1'>" &
        "<tr>" & Concat(Headers, "<th>" & Result & "</th>") & "</tr>" &
        "<tr>" & Concat(Units, "<th>" & Result & "</th>") & "</tr>" &
        Concat(
            Measurements,
            "<tr>" & Concat(Split(Value, ","), "<td align='middle'>" & Result & "</td>") & "</tr>"
        ) &
        "</table>")
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating the 'Measurements' value in the record scope for the With function, you are merging all lines into a single one - which is not what you want. If you have a data source called 'datasource', equivalent to the collection below:

```
ClearCollect(
    datasource,
    { data: "86, 50, 21, 411, 83, 60, 0, 112, 47, 118.5, 1.31, 3.79, 2.3, 70, 401, 125", serialno: "1", loadord: "1" },
    { data: "86, 50, 23, 416, 83, 60, 0, 113, 49, 117.3, 1.31, 3.76, 2.4, 65, 400, 124", serialno: "1", loadord: "1" },
    { data: "95, 50, 23, 436, 84, 60, 0, 115, 51, 131.3, 1.45, 3.69, 2.8, 65, 400, 136", serialno: "1", loadord: "1" },
    { data: "65, 50, 22, 389, 82, 60, 0, 112, 50, 92.8, .97, 3.76, 2.2, 60, 401, 93", serialno: "1", loadord: "1" },
    { data: "43, 50, 21, 332, 81, 60, 0, 104, 47, 63.3, .62, 3.86, .8, 50, 402, 62", serialno: "1", loadord: "1" },
    { data: "22, 50, 21, 237, 80, 60, 0, 101, 46, 35.3, .25, 4, .8, 40, 402, 32", serialno: "1", loadord: "1" },
    { data: "00, 50, 21, 122, 79, 60, 0, 95, 44, 11.7, .14, 4.14, .1, 35, 402, 0", serialno: "1", loadord: "1" }
)
```

Then you can use an expression similar to this one:

```
With(
    {
        Headers: Split("Power,Freq,Comp Intake,Exhaust,Eng Fresh Water,RW IN,RW OUT,Oil Sump,Inlet Manifold,Fuel Use,Boost,Engine Oil Press,Smoke,Blow by,Voltage,Current", ","),
        Units: Split("KWe,Hz,ºC,ºC,ºC,ºC,ºC,ºC,ºC,mm3/ST,Bar,Bar,FSN,L/min,volts,amps", ","),
        Measurements: SortByColumns(Search(Filter('datasource',Len(data) > 20),TextInput3.Text,"serialno"),"loadord")
    },
    "<table border='1'>" &
        "<tr>" & Concat(Headers, "<th>" & Result & "</th>") & "</tr>" &
        "<tr>" & Concat(Units, "<th>" & Result & "</th>") & "</tr>" &
        Concat(
            Measurements,
            "<tr>" & Concat(Split(data, ","), "<td align='middle'>" & Result & "</td>") & "</tr>"
        ) &
        "</table>")
```

Here's a way to read the part of the expression that adds the measurements to the table. I often find it useful to read the expressions "from the inside-out"

- The 'Filter' function is limiting the data from 'datasource' to only those that have a large enough value for the 'data' column
- The previous result is passed to the 'Search' function, to further filter those whose 'serialno' matches the value entered by the user in TextInput3
- The previous result is then sorted, based on the 'loadord' column; so far the result is a *table* of several measurement sets (each of them being comma-separated values for the individual measurements)
- The previous result is assigned the *alias* 'Measurements' in the With function. Notice that this is not strictly necessary - we could use the Sort(Search(Filter(...))) expression directly, but I find that breaking the expressions down makes it easier to understand them

  - Same for the headers - the aliasing done by the With function is not necessary; we could have the text `<tr><th>Power</th><th>Freq</th>...</tr>` directly in the expression instead of splitting and concatenating the comma-separated measurement names.
- The output of the expression is created by concatenating some strings. To concatenate all the rows of the table from the previous step into a single string, we use the outer Concat function - it will take each of the rows of the 'Measurements' and use it in the expression
- Since the measurements are comma-separated, we use the Split function to break it down, and another nested Concat call to wrap the individual values in `<td>...</td>` required to create the table.

[image: Expression and resulting table]

Comment: Hey Carlos! Thank you for responding on this question.

Is it possible to get in a call or chat with you as It looks like you have the answer but I am not quite understanding it, if you could that would be massively appreciated! Thank you again!

Comment: Hi Gregor, answers in StackOverflow should be self-contained so that other people that reach it can understand it. I edited the answer to add more details about how it works.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without hardcoding the entries as depending on what we search for we could get only 1 line or up to 7 lines ?

Comment: The updated answer split the test entries and the expression itself. The number of lines will depend on the result of the filter/search functions

Comment: Hi Carlos, first of all I am very appreciative of your help on this! It has gotten the desired result but I was wondering If I could ask a follow-up question regarding this and if I could show you the use case to help better understand why I am asking that question. 

Is there any other platform I can message you on ?

Comment: @GregorMilne the [Power Apps community](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Community/ct-p/PowerApps1) is a great way to get answers, and I'm active in that community as well (although I'm going out on vacation for about a week starting later today)